# Can we enforce a time limit?

Tags: discussion, policy

By time limit, I mean the OP should include one, such that (s)he will sooner or later accept the winning answer, provided there is at least one valid answer.

It doesn't have to be a fixed time. Something like "10 days after first answer" is good enough.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether your question is about how long to leave a question with answers before accepting one (to avoid discouraging new answers) or about whether acceptance should be final. If the latter, http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/542/should-i-change-the-accepted-answer is related.

Answer (score 3):

Acceptance is always in the gift of the asker.

I tend to accept after a week of so, and even included an "official" acceptance date and condition in [my highest voted question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2357/1p5-iterated-prisoners-dilemma).

I think that somthing between 1 and 2 weeks would be a good value for a "suggested default time to acceptence", but I don't feel that any attempt to enforce acceptence would be productive.